# Control to play video in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, video, flash

I am looking for free video player control which can play video in my .aspx page.
i am using c#,.net 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [**Flowplayer.**](http://flowplayer.org/)

Could be what you're looking for.

Comment: @JayMagwadiya, maybe you should be more specific then....... Can't read your mind.

Comment: Can you show me with an example so that i can understand that how to use this player

Comment: @JayMagwadiya, all the examples and the documentation can be found on their website. Did you look at it at least a bit? Or you're looking for some copy&paste type of answer without any real effort from your part? I'd gladly help, but you're not showing any effort at all and all your questions are way to general.

Comment: @walther Haha thats kinda funny , +1 for flowplayer

Answer (score 1):

**[JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)**

is a nice one supporting many formats and even supports Silver light works fine on java script/HTML5 too.... It's free and open source too.
and can be used with any web development platform as it is javascript..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **object** and **embed** html control and then pass the desired plugin as these blog posts shows

http://www.walkernews.net/2008/08/17/windows-media-player-how-to-embed-wmv-file-in-html-code/

http://www.walkernews.net/2008/01/11/how-to-embed-flv-flash-in-wordpress-or-html/

Comment: i did that but its only work in internet explorer , not crome and fierfox

Comment: Which type of file you are trying to run?

Comment: any type of file doesn't matter but this object didn't appear in other browser except microsoft explorer.It only show in IE.

Comment: i copy whole code and check it on all browser , Its only work in IE Because its Media player from microsoft. its not work in crome or firefox.

Comment: Link one is for media player but second one is using flashplayer, I have check flv files working properly